# PHP Symfony is it possible to return form via json in html code?

Tags: php, json, forms, api, symfony

I have a Symfony form and I want my API to return the rendered form HTML code via json, so I could insert it into my javascript and then insert/replace the HTML code into a modal.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs about JSON response here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response

If you want to pass rendered html, try this

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
...

$html = $this->render('your_form_template.html.twig', $ajaxParams)->getContent();
$response = new JsonResponse([
    'html' => $html
]);
return $response;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this solution helped, thanks!